# TranslateX with other distance

Tags: javascript, css

I made a infinite slide look like the owl carousel "center" (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html).
My problem is that when the second slide to far with the first slide, a smooth translate is so long.

Example: `translateX(-100px)` => `translateX(-1000px)`. I don't know what JS to write here. 
Here is my code in codepen (I want when I click the translate will fast look like owl carousel, I don't need the drag event).

Thanks for your help.

```js
var init = 120;
var listSlide = document.getElementById('list-slide');
listSlide.style.width = 120*8 + 'px';


function slideFirst() {
  var init = -120;
  listSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + init + "px)";
}
```

```css
#list{
  width: 480px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-inner{
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}

.list-inner .item{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div id="list">
    
    <div id="list-slide" class="list-inner" style="transform: translateX(-720px)">
      <div class="item">Item 01</div>
      <div class="item">Item 02</div>
      <div class="item">Item 03</div>
      <div class="item">Item 04</div>
      <div class="item">Item 05</div>
      <div class="item">Item 06</div>
      <div class="item">Item 07</div>
      <div class="item">Item 08</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <button onclick="slideFirst()">Click</button>
</div>
```

I tried to remove the transition and add it after that but it doesn't work.

```
var trans = -100;// a some distance
listSlide.style.transition = "all 0.25s ease 0s";

setTimeout(function(){
   listSlide.style.transition = "all 0s ease 0s";
   listSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + trans + 'px)';
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for you. I've changed some lines of code in js file and separated the with comments. Hope it will help you.

```js
var init = 120;
var listSlide = document.getElementById('list-slide');
listSlide.style.width = 120*8 + 'px';

// My code starts here

var sliderWidthTracker = -(120*6);

function slideFirst() {
  
  
  if (sliderWidthTracker < 0) {
    sliderWidthTracker = sliderWidthTracker+120;
    listSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + sliderWidthTracker + "px)";
  }
}

// My code ends here
```

```css
#list{
  width: 480px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-inner{
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}

.list-inner .item{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div id="list">
    
    <div id="list-slide" class="list-inner" style="transform: translateX(-720px)">
      <div class="item">Item 01</div>
      <div class="item">Item 02</div>
      <div class="item">Item 03</div>
      <div class="item">Item 04</div>
      <div class="item">Item 05</div>
      <div class="item">Item 06</div>
      <div class="item">Item 07</div>
      <div class="item">Item 08</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <button onclick="slideFirst()">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't understand my question. I made a infnite slider. I need change translateX -1000px to -100px fast. It's just a demo. I know translate step.

Comment: @PhátNguyễn I have added a new answer. Have a look. Did you ask for that?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the transition property and it is faster and smooth as well.

```
transition: all .8s ease 0s;
```

```js
var init = 120;
var listSlide = document.getElementById('list-slide');
listSlide.style.width = 120*8 + 'px';


function slideFirst() {
  var init = -120;
  listSlide.style.transform = "translateX(" + init + "px)";
}
```

```css
#list{
  width: 480px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-inner{
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .8s ease 0s;
}

.list-inner .item{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div id="list">
    
    <div id="list-slide" class="list-inner" style="transform: translateX(-720px)">
      <div class="item">Item 01</div>
      <div class="item">Item 02</div>
      <div class="item">Item 03</div>
      <div class="item">Item 04</div>
      <div class="item">Item 05</div>
      <div class="item">Item 06</div>
      <div class="item">Item 07</div>
      <div class="item">Item 08</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <button onclick="slideFirst()">Click</button>
</div>
```